# Retrieve the offset of <span> tag in web browser control C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html

I need to get the offset position of  tag...
I am using 
`HtmlElementCollection sp = textwebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");`
to get a collection of span tags....but in some cases even if i have span tags in the page,the count of the collection is zero...I guess it is because of some object tags with image information in between...example-

I don't know how to retrieve the offset of span tag in this case

HTML CODE:

```
<HTML><BODY>.....Using <OBJECT> and <EMBED><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>A Web page with a rolling die</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><OBJECT ID="Dieroll1"CLASSID="CLSID:46646B43-EA16-11CF-870C-00201801DDD6"CODEBASE="diero‌​ll.cab#Version=1,0,0,1"WIDTH="200"HEIGHT="200"><PARAM NAME="ForeColor" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="BackColor" VALUE="16777215"><PARAM NAME="Image" VALUE="beans.bmp"><EMBED LIVECONNECT NAME="Dieroll1"WIDTH="200"HEIGHT="200"CLASSID="CLSID:46646B43-EA16-11CF-870C-002‌​01801DDD6"TYPE="application/oleobject"CODEBASE="dieroll.cab#Version=1,0,0,1"PARAM‌​_ForeColor="0"PARAM_BackColor="16777215"></OBJECT><BR>Hthe die</BODY></HTML>Arrange to run Explorer when you debug the control.Here's the syntax for an OBJECT tag that sets the Image property:<OBJECTCLASSID="clsid:46646B43-EA16-11CF-870C-00201801DDD6"CODEBASE="http://www.gregcons.com/test/dieroll.ocx"ID=die1WIDTH=200HEIGHT=200ALIGN=centerHSPACE=0VSPACE=0><PARAM NAME="Dots" VALUE="1"><PARAM NAME="Image" VALUE="http://www.gregcons.com/test/beans.bmp">and the <span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>image</span> file you are using....</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: sorry...i cannot add the entire html code...as it is huge :(

Comment: add a part of html code not whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your html code in your question and i got all span tag with following code:(code must run after page loaded)

> ```
>  void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         List<HtmlElement> spanelement = new List<HtmlElement>();
>         foreach (HtmlElement span in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
>         {
>             spanelement.Add(span);
>             //Or Add Offset
>             //spanelement.Add(span.OffsetRectangle.Top;);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: ur code didn't work in my case..i guess its not the object tag but inner html due to which i am not able to get the span tags...plz add the above html code to the previous nd try if the code works..

Comment: `<OBJECT> and <EMBED> ......</HTML>` your html code dose not contain any span tag???!!!i used o second part of your html code

Comment: there were a lot of html tags in between my text...i removed those tags so as to get the correct offset of span tags

Answer (score 0):

give an id for the span tag and use

`document.getElementById('id')`

Comment: i tried...but its not working...As I had mentioned, I guess it is because of the object tags in between...Is there a way to remove these object tags, so that I would be able to get the location of <span> tag?